Why values in bar chart are invisible?
I use The Economist style to plot a bar chart to compare annual wages in three industries. My goal is to make the consulting industry looks far more greater than the other two by adjusting/manipulating the y-axis, but the three values are invisible. How can I fix it?
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

# Sample data
data <- data.frame(
  Category = c("Software Developers", "Economist", "Consulting"),
  Value = c(167540, 166070, 191000)
)

# Create the bar chart with adjusted y-axis limits
ggplot(data, aes(x = Category, y = Value, fill = Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_economist() +  # Economist color scheme
  theme_economist() +       # Economist theme
  labs(title = "Bar Chart in The Economist Style",
       subtitle = "Category vs Value",
       y = "Value",
       x = "Category") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(165000, 200000),  # Slightly below the smallest value
    breaks = seq(165000, 200000, 5000),  # Tighter breaks
    labels = scales::comma  # Use comma format for y-axis labels
  )



Barcharts start at zero. And as you set the limits at 16500 the bars got removed altogether as they do not fit into the limits. If you want to cut your bars (which in general should be avoided) use + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(165000, 200000)) which will "zoom" on the desired range.
